# Structure urls sub directory

Tags: structure

I'm using structure to build out a site. The site is in a sub folder for development. I can't get structure to write the correct paths. I have the menu showing the pages I've entered but the url just shows as

```
example.com/page/sub-page
```

when I want it to look like

```
example.com/sub-folder/index.php/page/sub-page.
```

If I go to

```
example.com/sub-folder/index.php/page/sub-page
```

It does show the correct page. 
Am I missing something obvious or is there something more complicated about having the site in a sub folder with structure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably already figured this out, but I just went through this issue as well.

I added a **site_url** tag to the structure tag and it fixed it:

`{exp:structure:nav max_depth="1" site_url="yes"}`